# Gmail Api returns error 503 service unavailable

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api, e2e-testing

I got this this code that gets email from my account. This works on one of our automation process. But using another account im getting a service unavailable error

```
    private static GmailService GetGmailService()
    {
        string credPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(Path.Combine(credPath, "credentials.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
              System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var credPath2 = Path.Combine(path, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath2, true)).Result;
        }

        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,

        });
        return service;
    }


    public static string GetRegistrationLink(string devEmail, string toEmail, string subjectSearch = "", string keywords = "")
    {
        var url = string.Empty;
        var service = GetGmailService();
        var inboxlistRequest = service.Users.Messages.List(devEmail);
        inboxlistRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";

        var query = @"in:unread in:inbox subject:Reset your CS Professional Suite Web account password";
        //@"in:unread ";
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subjectSearch))
        //    query += $"subject:{subjectSearch} ";
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEmail))
        //    query += $"to:{toEmail} ";
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
        //    query += $@"{keywords}";

        //inboxlistRequest.Q = query;
        inboxlistRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;

        //get our emails
        var emailListResponse = inboxlistRequest.Execute();
        if (emailListResponse != null && emailListResponse.Messages != null)
        {
            //loop through each email and get what fields you want... 
            foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)
            {
                var emailInfoRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get(devEmail, email.Id);
                var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.Execute();
                if (emailInfoResponse == null) continue;
                var from = "";
                var date = "";
                foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                {
                    switch (mParts.Name)
                    {
                        case "Date":
                            date = mParts.Value;
                            break;
                        case "From":
                            @from = mParts.Value;
                            break;

                    }

                    if (date == "" || @from == "") continue;
                    var messageBodyParts = emailInfoResponse.Payload?.Parts?.SelectMany(a => a.Parts).ToList();
                    if (messageBodyParts == null) continue;
                    foreach (var p in messageBodyParts)
                    {
                        if (p.MimeType != "text/html") continue;
                        byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(p.Body.Data);
                        var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                        url = Regex.Match(decodedString, "href\\s*=\\s*\"(?<url>.*?)\"").Groups["url"].Value;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return url;
    }
```

The api has been enabled and the credentials has been included on the project but it is returning the 503 service not available error. But when i run the same code on a console, it works fine with the same credentials.json

Comment: How many requests are you making? That code looks very familiar as well :)

Comment: just single request. Not more than 5 request during the debugging session

Comment: No you are not just making a single request; you're making many. `foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)` inside you are making many requestes based on the `Messages` object (`emailInfoRequest.Execute();`) is your guy. Do you know what that code is doing?

Comment: i believe not. Those are the messages from the single request. getting the messages. I was looking at the dashboard. and how could it be explained when the code works on some other projects and on a console app. the same piece of code

Comment: Can you explain where you got that code?

Comment: and to add. this code specifically fails when saving the credential response to a file with the mentioned error message

Comment: You're doing many things wrong, you're creating a new service every time you're calling `GetRegistrationLink` as well as the comment I left above.

Comment: That specific error could be caused by too many requests and or a transient condition, which can be corrected by retrying with a backoff.. Also, every request counts against your account and it's limited as well.

Comment: (1) So you're using different accounts to run this, and it works with one and not with the other? (2) You say you `run the same code on a console, it works fine`. How are you running it when it fails? (3) Also, have you tried making one request outside the `foreach` (or tried logging `emailInfoResponse` to see whether any request is being made at all) in order to make sure this is not a problem of making too many requests?

Comment: If request are the concern, then why there are very few request from the dashboard? Yes on this account and on this E2E TEST. I am not having problem with this code on one of our E2E. And on a console application it's just plain console application.

Comment: If the code is working on some projects and not in others, it would be useful to have more information on the projects where this is failing. Apart from that, have you tried any of the things that have been proposed to you, in order to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @lamblichus Yes I have even observe the dashboard for the request made. It's not like what they have mentioned. This was working on the same project template that we use. but with this only project it fails.

Comment: As I said before, if the code is working on some projects and not in others, it would be useful to have more information on the projects where this is failing.